# Scrollable container in webpage

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I want to create a viewport inside a webpage with scrollbars.

In this viewport I want to place a collage of images at arbitrary offsets relative to each other.

The first image I add should be centred in the viewport.  It may not be as big as the viewport.

As other images are added over time, they are some polar coordinates from some other image.  I can turn polar coordinates into X Y offsets.

As I add images, I may want them to be left of all other images or above all other images and so on; can I use negative offsets?  Can the scrollbars on the viewport scroll over the used coordinate range of the children automatically, rather than being from 0,0?

What container class with which CSS settings do I use for the viewport?  What CSS position settings do I use to position the children?

Comment: It sounds like you want a coordinate grid, 0,0 x,y, right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish if the top-most image must have the Y 0, and the left-most X 0, does this mean that I have to programmatically go and move all the other images if I add a new left-most or top-most?

Comment: It seems as if you're delimiting origin. Somewhere you're going to need to know what represents 0,0, I think. It seems like you're graphing, although the user interaction is "graph-literal" but non-interactive.

Comment: You can fudge it, in a way: http://jsfiddle.net/n37rz/

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've tried to clarify in the question text

Comment: I believe your concern is something [along these lines](http://jsfiddle.net/n37rz/1/), whereby coordinates may lead to content that is not accessible if the wrong technique is used. (And I may be caught up in the capture of the position, and not the display, but your inclusion of scrollbar as a tag makes me suspicious.)

Answer (score 12):

To make a div or block element scroll able use the overflow property: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

For positioning, and size check this out: 
http://www.wickham43.net/divboxes.php

Here's a CSS collage gallery i googled in 1 second. 
http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/collage_gallery.asp#.T42Z06uXQ_Q

(Your question isn't specific, if the above doesn't help please edit)

Comment: Your last link 404'd.